# Dimensions of query webmasters tools api

Tags: google-api-webmasters

specially Alex :)

I want to know if any body have a PHP code to get the details of a query from webmasters tools api.

I have already the query dimensions but I dont't know how exactely to make it with PHP code.

```
$webmastersService = new Google_Service_Webmasters($client);
$searchanalytics = $webmastersService->searchanalytics;
$request = new Google_Service_Webmasters_SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supposing, that you have all credentials and tokens. If you don't have them, you'll get `(401) Login Required` error.

Making request you can set `startDate, endDate, searchType, rowLimit` via setter methods like this:

```
$query->setStartDate('2015-11-10');
```

But some methods require array like `setDimensions`:

```
$query->setDimensions(array('page'));
```

To more complicate the things `setDimensionFilterGroups` method requires array of `Google_Service_Webmasters_ApiDimensionFilterGroup` . And every `Google_Service_Webmasters_ApiDimensionFilterGroup` instance requires filters to be set via `setFilters` method with an array of `Google_Service_Webmasters_ApiDimensionFilter`.

And for `Google_Service_Webmasters_ApiDimensionFilter` you can set dimension, operator and expression via `setDimension, setOperator, setExpression` methods.

For additional info on these types, classes and methods please refer to https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Service/Webmasters.php

Consider, you want pages (dimensions=page) the given day (startdate, enddate) and filter results for a given search query. To create a filter you need to set dimension to query, operator to equals and expression to your keyword.

This request in API Explorer looks like:

[image]

So the code to get all pages of example.com site that were displayed 2015-11-10 in reply to "weird things" search query is below:

```
    $query = new Google_Service_Webmasters_SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest();
    $query->setDimensions(array('page'));
    $query->setStartDate('2015-11-10');
    $query->setEndDate('2015-11-10');

    $filter = new Google_Service_Webmasters_ApiDimensionFilter();
    $filter->setDimension('query');
    $filter->setOperator('equals');
    $filter->setExpression('weird things');

    $filtergroup = new Google_Service_Webmasters_ApiDimensionFilterGroup();
    $filtergroup->setFilters(array($filter));
    $query->setDimensionFilterGroups(array($filtergroup));

    $response = $service->searchanalytics->query('http://example.com/', $query);
```

That is simplified demo code. May be it has some mistakes.

And I want to note, that Python API is much easier and clearer.

Comment: thanks @alex that was a great help from you, thanks a lot.

Comment: I have another question about the crawl stats, I will make a new question for that with explinations, thanks a lot again @alex

Comment: Here is another question, thank you so much [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33957888/how-to-get-crawl-stats-from-webmaster-tools-api)