# How to get crawl stats FROM webmaster tools api

Tags: google-api-webmasters

I want to get this graph datas :

I can't add an image here : [graph.png](http://lala-l7adga.com/graph.png) I don't have the reputation 10.

So I want to get for each day the 3 values (Pages crawled per day, kilobytes downloaded per day, time spent downloading a page)

the idea is to get an array like this :

```
$datas['2015-11-20']['pages_crawled'] = 125;
$datas['2015-11-20']['kilobytes'] = 1452;
$datas['2015-11-20']['time_spent'] = 1023;


$datas['2015-11-21']['pages_crawled'] = 146;
$datas['2015-11-21']['kilobytes'] = 2410;
$datas['2015-11-21']['time_spent'] = 1563;

$datas['2015-11-22']['pages_crawled'] = 102;
$datas['2015-11-22']['kilobytes'] = 1560;
$datas['2015-11-22']['time_spent'] = 1400;
```

Something like this.

thanks specially to @alex for his greathfull Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't get this Crawl Stats via API.

The only supported methods are `webmasters.urlcrawlerrorscounts.query`, `webmasters.urlcrawlerrorssamples.list`, `webmasters.urlcrawlerrorssamples.get`, `webmasters.urlcrawlerrorssamples.markAsFixed` ( https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/webmasters/v3/ )

So you can get information about crawl errors, but not general crawl stats.

Answer (score 0):

The crawl errors you can retrieve with this API call :

`https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mywebsite.com/urlCrawlErrorsCounts/query?latestCountsOnly=true&fields=countPerTypes&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

But the crawl statistics are not exposed through API.