# How to get more than 5000 query from webmasters tools api?

Tags: php, google-api-webmasters

I want to know if there is a possibility to get more than 5000 records from webmasters tools API as the max limit is 5000 records.

Here is my code :

```
//==========INITIALISE CLIENT==========//
$client->setAccessToken($code_webmasters);
$webmastersService = new Google_Service_Webmasters($client);
$searchanalytics = $webmastersService->searchanalytics;
//=====================================//
$date = "2015-11-22";
$request = new Google_Service_Webmasters_SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest;
$request->setStartDate($date);
$request->setEndDate($date);
$request->setDimensions(array('query'));
$request->setSearchType("web");
$request->setRowLimit(5000);
$qsearch = $searchanalytics->query($site['name'], $request);
$rows = $qsearch->getRows();
```

As you know in analytics API it is possible to get more than the max limit by using :

```
'start-index' => 1, 'max-results' => 10000
```

But in webmasters tools api I can't find those parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use pagination in webmasters tools api, You can't increase your plan account to get more  records in one call using rowLimit field (MAX 5,000) .

Source: https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/searchanalytics/query

Sorry